# Slow livereload with grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, livereload, compass

Apologies in advance I'm very new to this, I previously was using Durandal with NPM and had liverealod working and it was lightning fast, now I'm using grunt with angular and my livereload has gotten much slower, sometimes 4-5 seconds.  Didn't know if this was anything I could speed up due to my lack of experience setting up the build.

```
watch: {
  bower: {
    files: ['bower.json'],
    tasks: ['wiredep']
  },
  js: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    }
  },
  jsTest: {
    files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
    tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
  },
  compass: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
  },
  gruntfile: {
    files: ['Gruntfile.js']
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
    },
    files: [
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
      '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    ]
  }
},
```

---

```
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
        ];
      }
    }
  },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!!

Comment: I think 3-4 seconds seems normal, especially if you're compiling SASS to css, which it looks like you are.

Comment: Ok, I think I was mostly just curious since the developer was previously using some type of Durandal configuration and npm and it was like instantaneous.  Sorry if I'm confusing the terminology, I'm a designer and already treading in the deep end :)